# How to change to type of response to Map in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-http

I try to make a GET http call from flutter to Nodejs. The data I get is in json form but when I try to manipulate it with flutter I can't because the response is of type `RESPONSE` or I can change it to `string` I don't know how to change the `response` to type `Map` to help me manipulate the data I get.

here the code :

```
Future getYear() async {
    var url = "http://192.168.1.19:3000/getyear";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var jsonresponse = await json.decode(json.encode(response.body));
  }
```

and here the data I get but I can't manipulate it `[{"year":2019},{"year":2020}]`

Comment: What's the point of decoding the encoded body? Isn#t the body already json encoded? Please see [the flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) on how to do this.

Comment: I don't know the point of decoding and encoding the body but when I try to post in anther method is not working only with this way that's why I try to do it another time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsonDecode(response.body)` decodes the response to `Map<String,dynamic>`.

Comment: `jsonDecode(response.body)` return type `list` not `Map`

Comment: A list of Maps maybe ?

Comment: I don't know I try this but is not working `List<Map<String, dynamic>> b = jsonDecode(response.body);` as a list of Maps I get this error `_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>')`

Comment: but I can go to the backend and change the type of response to make it list there I try it and it's work with your solution

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class for it that would look like so:

```dart
class Year {
  int year;

  Year({this.year});

  Year.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    year = json['year'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['year'] = this.year;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Than you simply call

```dart
Year.fromJson(jsonresponse)
```

Comment: in the `Year.formJson(Map<String,dynamic>json)` I get this error under the `Year`  `Non-nullable instance field 'year' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'.`

Comment: and I have to make the `constructor` like this `Year({required this.year});`